# On epoll_pwait, POSIX timers and X11 events. Most of X11 events is either delayed or dropped

Tags: c, linux, signals, epoll, xcb

The setup is below.

```
have a X11 connection file descriptor x11_fd set in non-blocking mode.
have a signal file descriptor sig_fd         set in non-blocking mode.
create a POSIX timer with timer_create

add all above in epoll set

main_loop:
 n = epoll_pwait(ep_fd, ep_evs, MAXEVENTS, -1, &mask_sigs)
  if(fd == sig_fd)
   do set some signal flags
  if(fd == x11_fd)
   do X11 events
  if(fd == timer_fd or timeout)
   do some small computations
end_main_loop
```

X11 events are processed with `while((event = xcb_poll_for_event(...)))`

The timer was set to expire at `4 second` rate. And all `X11` events were deliwered in order and non were dropped. Now, **if the timer is set to have a sub-second rate**, the X11 events got delayed or completely dropped.

The problem is, the application may need a high-rate timers.

My naive thought was that `epoll` will queue the `X11` events while callbacks generated by `POSIX` timers are processing. The `epoll` seems lacking of a `CPU` time or something. Honestly I do not know why is `X11` events got dropped. I just want to overcome it. Preferably with some multiplexing and **without** threading.

**Update**

I removed the timer and had set `epoll_pwait` timeout to minimum. The problem still persists. I had to note that events are not dropped, but got queued and recieved in batch. Also, the delayed events are not all events that I do listen to. Mouse movement, focus, leave/enter displayed without delay. Also the application behaves very strangely in a way, that, when i move mouse, or move window, or do some other interaction(I do not get what kind of interaction is it), the keyboard gets pulled at higher rate.

Need some help here. Can post a code with some scripts to `github`.

**Update**

Well, after some thoughts, I think that interaction with `X11` and a computational task that must be run at constant rate do not integrate well in multiplexing paradigm. The one `epoll_wait` for all computing seem to change time frequency of multiplexed tasks of a different kind.

**Update**

Changed the pseudocode to reflect that I do some small computations in a event loop.

**N.B.**

Timer event frequency is higher then the `X11` event frequency. X server events get in-between the timer events and screw the processing.

Comment: Don't post pseudo code. Post your actual code.  Automobile mechanics can't fix your car based on your mere ***description***.

Comment: @AndrewHenle point taken

Comment: "x11_fd set in non-blocking mode." <- What do you mean? Are you using `xcb_get_file_descriptor()` and then making the returned FD non-blocking? Uhm. Don't do that. Do things start working better when you don't do that?

Comment: @UliSchlachter Honestly I had just set all my fd's to be non-blocking mode. The reason behind this is that a signal fd have a small amount of data to read, so I **almost** sure that the read would return all data. The `TCP` is desined to be buffered so one needs to be prepared for that anyway. As for the `X11` part... Honestly I did not read the `XCB` source code to have a meaningless understanding what does non-blocking mode does to `X11`.

Comment: @UliSchlachter I just wish that polling for xcb events do all magic with the data avaibility.

Comment: @UliSchlachter No, the bloking mode for `X11` `fd` did'nt change anything. Still noticable event lag with a computations added.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Maybe a little off-topic, but here is https://lowres.cartooncollections.com/cars-diagnosis-garages-automobiles-mechanic-transport-CS172338_low.jpg. **A little**, because it did mention computer. Actually, the thing did not need my description **at all**.

Comment: Do you do any interaction with the `xcb_connection_t` outside of "do X11 events"? Do you handle events in a loop? (Call `xcb_poll_for_event()` until it returns `NULL`?) XCB has an internal queue of events that it already read from the connection but did not yet return to the caller. Both of the above could mean that you call `epoll_pwait()` even though there are pending events in XCB's internal queue. (Also: libxcb definitely doesn't handle the case where you change its FD to be non-blocking, but the symptoms for that error should be different.)

Comment: Also, your code is still pseudocode, so all I can do is guess. If you could provide a self-contained example that actually reproduces your problem on my machine, then I could test these theories myself and would have a much better understanding on what is going on.

Comment: @UliSchlachter Thanks for your time. I will, today or later.

Comment: @UliSchlachter I got a new question that is my elaboration on the subject. As I understand it right now, `epoll_wait` does not "like" to have `X11` events with timers/timeouts. As for this question, I try to post some code, if the code conveniently fit the SO format.

Comment: @UliSchlachter Regarding your comment about how do I handle `X11` events. I do that, as written in a pseudocode: wait on `x11_fd` then call `xcb_poll_for_event` untill `NULL`. The problem is, I do not know how `XCB` handles its reads from X server. I had put my trust in `epoll` set and fd method. So, as soon as any data avaible, I do polling for `XCB` events.