# What is the frequency of epoll_wait "wakeups"?

Tags: c, linux, x11, epoll, xcb

This question is elaboration and continuation of my previous question - [On epoll_pwait, POSIX timers and X11 events. Most of X11 events is either delayed or dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65906541/8339821). I work with `XCB` window that displays some graphical information. The application has an insteractive input and **had** more or less static display. Now the requirenments had changed and I need to add some pereodic computations **and** have a interactive input.

The problem with the new requirenments is that computations goes at high rate. With that, I get inconsistent interaction with the `XCB` window. Input may lag behind, or change the rate of processing.

The setup is multiplex events with `epoll_pwait`. The events are signals, X11 events and recently added timers/timeout.

What I understand as of now, I need to separate user interaction from the computations. The problem with my setup, as of now, is that rate of `X11` events changes in a way I can't explain.

So I decide to separate waiting on `X11` events with the rest of the logic. Can you suggest a proper way to do it? Will having a `X11` window in a separate `thread`/`process`/`epoll set` help?

And the actual question, as I look upon it now, is, what is a frequency of `epoll_wait` wakeups? I plan to have one `epoll_wait` in a loop. Maybe some processes to be wait on. I understand that `epoll_wait` will "wakeup" at some random points int time.

**Update**

My setup is close to this one:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/signalfd.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <xcb/xcb.h>

static struct timespec  tm_p, tm_c, tm_diff;
static unsigned long    nevents = 0;

static inline void timespec_diff(struct timespec *a, struct timespec *b, struct timespec *res) {
    res->tv_sec  = a->tv_sec  - b->tv_sec;
    res->tv_nsec = a->tv_nsec - b->tv_nsec;
    if (res->tv_nsec < 0) {
        --res->tv_sec;
        res->tv_nsec += 1000000000L;
    }
}

static double compute(){
 double t     = 1.0;
 double eps   = 1e-7;
 double eps_2 = eps / 2.0;

 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tm_p);
 while(t > eps){
  t -= eps;
  t += eps;
  t -= eps_2 + eps_2;
 }
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tm_c);
 timespec_diff(&tm_c, &tm_p, &tm_diff);
 printf(" compute: %ld %f\n", tm_diff.tv_sec, tm_diff.tv_nsec / 1e9); 

 return (int)t;
}

/* defines for epoll */
#define MAXEVENTS 64
#define SET_EV(_ev,_fd,_events) _ev.data.fd = _fd; _ev.events = _events

static int xcb_get_atom(xcb_connection_t *c,
                        const char       *name, 
                        xcb_atom_t       *atom)
{
 xcb_intern_atom_cookie_t  cookie;
 xcb_generic_error_t      *error;
 xcb_intern_atom_reply_t  *reply;

 cookie = xcb_intern_atom(c, 0, strlen(name), name);
 reply  = xcb_intern_atom_reply(c, cookie, &error);
 if(NULL == reply){
  free(error);
  return -1;
 }
 
 *atom = reply->atom; 
 free(reply);

 return 0;
}

static int xcb_change_prop_wm_close(xcb_connection_t *c,
                                    xcb_window_t      window,
                                    xcb_atom_t        wm_p, 
                                    xcb_atom_t        atom)
{
 xcb_void_cookie_t    cookie;
 xcb_generic_error_t *error;

 xcb_atom_enum_t      type     = XCB_ATOM_ATOM;
 uint8_t              format   = 32;
 uint32_t             data_len = 1;

 cookie = xcb_change_property_checked(c,                      /* xcb connection                 */
                                      XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE,  /* mode                           */
                                      window,                 /* window                         */
                                      wm_p,                   /* the property to change         */ 
                                      type,                   /* type of the property           */
                                      format,                 /* format(bits)                   */
                                      data_len,               /* number of elements(see format) */
                                      &atom                   /* property data                  */
                                     );
 error = xcb_request_check(c, cookie);
 if (error) {
  free(error);
  return -1;
 }

 return 0;
}

int main()
{
  xcb_connection_t *c;
  xcb_screen_t     *screen;
  xcb_window_t      win;
  xcb_atom_t        a_wm_p;
  xcb_atom_t        wm_p_close;

 struct epoll_event       ep_ev, *ep_evs = NULL;
 struct signalfd_siginfo  siginf;
 sigset_t                 mask_sigs, mask_osigs;
 int                      sig_fd = -1, x11_fd = -1, ep_fd = -1, tm_fd = -1;

 /* set up signals */
 if(sigemptyset(&mask_sigs) < 0){
  perror(" * sigemptyset(&mask_sigs)");
  goto main_terminate; 
 }
 if(sigaddset(&mask_sigs, SIGINT)){   /* these signals will be blocked. the signals will arrive */
  perror(" * sigaddset(&mask_sigs, SIGINT)");
  goto main_terminate; 
 }
 if(sigaddset(&mask_sigs, SIGQUIT)){  /*  to epoll and not to a default signal handler.         */
  perror(" * sigaddset(&mask_sigs, SIGQUIT)");
  goto main_terminate; 
 }

 /* save old sigmask, replace it with new sigmask */
 if(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask_sigs, &mask_osigs) < 0){
  perror(" * sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask_sigs, &mask_osigs)");
  goto main_terminate;
 }

 /* get signal file descriptor */
 if((sig_fd = signalfd(-1, &mask_sigs, 0)) < 0){
  perror(" * signalfd(-1, &mask_sigs, 0)");
  goto main_terminate;
 }

 /* set signal fd as non-blocking */
 {
  int on = 1;

  if(ioctl(sig_fd, FIONBIO, (char *)&on) < 0){
   perror(" * ioctl(sig_fd, FIONBIO)");
   goto main_terminate;
  }
 }

  /* Open the connection to the X server */
  c = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);

  /* Get the first screen */
  screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (xcb_get_setup (c)).data;

  /* Ask for our window's Id */
  win = xcb_generate_id(c);

  /* Create the window */
 {
  unsigned int         cw_mask = XCB_CW_BORDER_PIXEL
                               | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK
  ;
  /* values must follow in the incresing order of the cw_mask constants */
  unsigned int         cw_values[] = {screen->white_pixel,
                                      XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS|XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_RELEASE
  };
  xcb_create_window (c,                             /* Connection          */
                     XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,          /* depth (same as root)*/
                     win,                           /* window Id           */
                     screen->root,                  /* parent window       */
                     0, 0,                          /* x, y                */
                     150, 150,                      /* width, height       */
                     10,                            /* border_width        */
                     XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT, /* class               */
                     screen->root_visual,           /* visual              */
                     cw_mask, cw_values);           /* masks               */
 }

 /* get x11 connection file descriptor */
 x11_fd = xcb_get_file_descriptor(c);

 /* atom WM_PROTOCOLS */
 if(xcb_get_atom(c, "WM_PROTOCOLS", &a_wm_p) < 0){
  fprintf(stderr, " %s:%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
  return -1;
 }
 /* atom window close */
 if(xcb_get_atom(c, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", &wm_p_close) < 0){
  fprintf(stderr, " %s:%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
  return -1;
 }
 { /* wm prop: intercept close */
  if(xcb_change_prop_wm_close(c, win, a_wm_p, wm_p_close) < 0){
   fprintf(stderr, " %s:%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
   goto main_terminate;
  }
 }

 /* create epoll set file descriptor */
 if((ep_fd = epoll_create(1)) < 0){
  perror(" * epoll_create");
  goto main_terminate;
 }

 /* allocate events for epoll queue  */
 if(NULL == (ep_evs = (struct epoll_event*)calloc(MAXEVENTS,sizeof(ep_ev)))){
  perror(" * calloc(MAXEVENTS)");
  goto main_terminate;
 }

 { /* fd timer */
  struct itimerspec ts;
  
  if((tm_fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TFD_NONBLOCK)) < 0){
   perror(" * timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TFD_NONBLOCK)");
   goto main_terminate;
  }

  ts.it_value.tv_sec     = 1;
  ts.it_value.tv_nsec    = 0;
  ts.it_interval.tv_sec  = 0;
  ts.it_interval.tv_nsec = (unsigned long)10e6; /* 10 msec */

  if(timerfd_settime(tm_fd, 0, &ts, NULL) < 0){
   perror(" * timerfd_settime(tm_fd, 0, &ts, NULL)");
   goto main_terminate;
  }
 }

 /* add X11 event */
 SET_EV(ep_ev,x11_fd,EPOLLIN);
 if(epoll_ctl (ep_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, x11_fd, &ep_ev) < 0){
  perror(" * epoll_ctl x11_fd");
  goto main_terminate;
 }

 /* add timer event */
 SET_EV(ep_ev,tm_fd,EPOLLIN);
 if(epoll_ctl (ep_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, tm_fd, &ep_ev) < 0){
  perror(" * epoll_ctl tm_fd");
  goto main_terminate;
 }

 /* add signal event */
 SET_EV(ep_ev,sig_fd,EPOLLIN);
 if(epoll_ctl (ep_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sig_fd, &ep_ev) < 0){
  perror(" * epoll_ctl sig_fd");
  goto main_terminate;
 }

 /* window title */
 const char *title = "epoll_pwait";
 xcb_change_property (c,
                      XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE,
                      win,
                      XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME,
                      XCB_ATOM_STRING,
                      8,
                      strlen (title),
                      title );

  /* Map the window on the screen */
  xcb_map_window (c, win);

  /* Make sure commands are sent before we pause, so window is shown */
  xcb_flush (c);

 while(1){
  int  n, i, fd, status;
  bool f_compute   = false;
  bool f_exit_sig  = false;
  bool f_win_close = false;

  n = epoll_pwait (ep_fd, ep_evs, MAXEVENTS, -1, &mask_sigs); /* wait, signal safe */

  if(n < 0){
   fprintf(stderr, " * main(): %s:%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
   status = 1;
   goto main_terminate;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){ /* service epoll events */
   fd = ep_evs[i].data.fd;

   if(fd == sig_fd){ /* signal */
    status = read(fd, &siginf, sizeof(siginf));
   if(status != sizeof(siginf)){
    fprintf(stderr,"read != sizeof(siginf)");
    goto main_terminate;
   }
   if(siginf.ssi_signo == SIGINT){
     printf("got SIGINT\n");
     f_exit_sig = true;
    }else if(siginf.ssi_signo == SIGQUIT){
     printf("got SIGQUIT\n");
     f_exit_sig = true;
     goto main_terminate;
    }else {
     printf("got unregistered signal\n");
    }
   }else if(fd == x11_fd){ /* x11 event */
    xcb_generic_event_t *event;

    while((event = xcb_poll_for_event(c))){
     if (event && (event->response_type == 0)){ /* error recieved */
      free(event);
      goto main_terminate;
     }

     switch(event->response_type & ~0x80){

     case XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE: { /* window close */
       xcb_client_message_event_t *ce = (xcb_client_message_event_t*)event;

       if(ce->data.data32[0] == wm_p_close){ /* window should close */
        f_win_close = true;
       }
      } break;
      case XCB_KEY_PRESS: { /* keyboard key press */
       printf("XCB_KEY_PRESS\n");
       nevents++;
      } break; 

     } /* end switch */
     free(event);

    } /* end while event loop */
   }else if(fd == tm_fd){ /* timer event */
    uint64_t  overrun;

    status = read(fd, &overrun, sizeof(uint64_t));
    if(status != EAGAIN) {
     //~ printf(" ! timer overruns: %lu\n", overrun);
    }
    f_compute = true;
   }
  } /* finish service epoll events */
  
  if(f_exit_sig){ /* exit signal */
   goto main_terminate;
  }
  if(f_win_close){ /* window close */
   goto main_terminate;
  }

  if(f_compute){ /* do some computations */
   compute();
   xcb_flush(c);
  }

 } /* end while(1) */

main_terminate:
 if(sig_fd != -1){
  close(sig_fd);
 }
 if(tm_fd != -1){
  close(tm_fd);
 }
 if(ep_fd != -1){
  close(ep_fd);
 }
 if(ep_evs){
  free(ep_evs);
 }
 xcb_disconnect(c);

 if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask_osigs, NULL) < 0){
  perror(" * sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask_osigs, NULL)");
 }

 printf("received %lu events\n", nevents);

 return 0;
}
```

With the above, I can not reproduce input lag I do have in more verbose program. I test the above with `xdotool`, send some input `X11` events, and my eye can't catch any visible input delay. All events get delivered. For now I can not post a full code that I have problem with.

Answer (score 2):

> what is a frequency of `epoll_wait` wakeups?

I'll assume you are talking about the precision of wakeups. This surely depends on kernel details, but let's just make an experiment: We can write a small program that tests how long `epoll_wait` takes. This will test both a timeout of zero and a timeout of 1 ms since a timeout of zero might be treated specially.

Output on my system:

```
         empty: avg 0.015636 μs, min 0.014 μs, max 0.065 μs
    sleep 1 ms: avg 1108.55 μs, min 1014.72 μs, max 1577.42 μs
  epoll_wait 0: avg 0.761084 μs, min 0.38 μs, max 37.787 μs
  epoll_wait 1: avg 1108.97 μs, min 1017.22 μs, max 2602.4 μs
```

Doing nothing (`empty`) measures less than a microsecond, so the following results should be somewhat reliable. The minimum time is also not zero, so the clock has enough precision for what we are doing.

Sleeping 1 ms sleeps at least 1.014 ms, but there also was a case of 1.5 ms. I guess that means that wakeups are not all that precise.

Using `epoll_wait()` to do nothing take less than a microsecond. More than doing nothing, but this still does basically nothing, so perhaps this really just measures the syscall overhead...?

Sleeping 1 ms with `epoll_wait()` behaves more or less the same as sleeping for 1 ms with `nanosleep()`.

If you want to improve this experiment, you could actually register some FDs via `epoll_ctl()`. It might be that the kernel handles "empty" epoll FDs specially.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MEASUREMENT_COUNT 10000
#define NUM_EVENTS 42

static int epoll_fd;

double diff_micro_sec(struct timespec *a, struct timespec *b) {
    double sec = a->tv_sec - b->tv_sec;
    double ns = a->tv_nsec - b->tv_nsec;
    return sec * 1e6 + ns / 1e3;
}


static void empty(void) {
}

static void sleep_one_ms(void) {
    struct timespec spec;
    spec.tv_sec = 0;
    spec.tv_nsec = 1000 * 1000;
    nanosleep(&spec, NULL);
}

static void epoll_wait_0(void) {
    struct epoll_event events[NUM_EVENTS];
    epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, NUM_EVENTS, 0);
}

static void epoll_wait_1(void) {
    struct epoll_event events[NUM_EVENTS];
    epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, NUM_EVENTS, 1);
}

static void do_it(const char *name, void (*func)(void)) {
    double sum, min, max;
    struct timespec a, b;

    for (int i = 0; i < MEASUREMENT_COUNT; i++) {
        double diff;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &a);
        func();
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &b);

        diff = diff_micro_sec(&b, &a);

        if (i == 0) {
            sum = diff;
            min = diff;
            max = diff;
        } else {
            sum += diff;
            if (diff < min)
                min = diff;
            if (diff > max)
                max = diff;
        }
    }

    printf("%14s: avg %g μs, min %g μs, max %g μs\n", name, sum / MEASUREMENT_COUNT, min, max);
}

int main() {
    do_it("empty", empty);
    do_it("sleep 1 ms", sleep_one_ms);
    epoll_fd = epoll_create(1);
    do_it("epoll_wait 0", epoll_wait_0);
    do_it("epoll_wait 1", epoll_wait_1);
    close(epoll_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have posted the code, as per request. The posted code is some mix and match of my whole program. My original code uses even less computation time, the timeouts are the same. Still I have a mentioned problem. I think I have to seek some mistake elswhere in the original code.